# Copiar uma List para outra List sem dependências

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, lista

Como faço para copiar dados de uma list para outra de forma que fiquem independentes uma da outra? Tenho uma list<> de uma classe que criei onde os dados nela inseridos, vão aparecendo numa listBox, e queria copiar tudo o que está nessa list para uma nova. Eu consegui copiar tudo de uma para outra, mas quando trabalho com a segunda lista, a original (primeira list) sofre alterações indesejadas.

Esta é a minha classe:

```
public class vao
{
    public int quantidade { get; set; }
    public double medida { get; set; }
}
```

Esta é a forma como estou a inserir os dados na list e a fazer com que sejam 
apresentados na listbox.

```
    List<vao> vaos = new List<vao>();
    List<vao> ordenada = new List<vao>();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        vao A = new vao();
        A.quantidade = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        A.medida = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);
        vaos.Add(A);

        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        foreach (vao item in vaos)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(item.quantidade + " x " + item.medida);
        }

        textBox1.Text = "";
        textBox1.Focus();
        textBox2.Text = "";
    }
```

E esta forma é como estou a copiar tudo de uma list(vaos) para a list(Ordenada)
e a apresentar o que esta na list(ordenada) numa nova listbox da forma que desejaria.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ordenada = vaos;

        for (int i = 0; i <= ordenada.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < ordenada.Count; j++)
            {
                if (ordenada[i].medida < ordenada[j].medida)
                {
                    int aux_qt = ordenada[i].quantidade;
                    ordenada[i].quantidade = ordenada[j].quantidade;
                    ordenada[j].quantidade = aux_qt;

                    Double aux_med = ordenada[i].medida;
                    ordenada[i].medida = ordenada[j].medida;
                    ordenada[j].medida = aux_med;
                }
            }
        }

        listBox2.Items.Clear();
        foreach (var item in ordenada)
        {
            listBox2.Items.Add(item.quantidade + " x " + item.medida);
        }

    }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Neste caso inseri as quantidades e as medidas e carreguei para copiar e ordenar.
[image: List já com dados]

Quando selecciono um index da lista Original os valores que têm são os que estão na lista Ordenada
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando se atribui uma lista à outra lista da forma tradicional ex: listaA = listaB. A listaA vai referenciar o mesmo espaço de memória da listaB. Com isso qualquer mudança dos objetos de uma das listas será alterada na outra lista.
A solução seria definir um novo local na memória para a listaA.

Uma solução possível seria criar uma classe com o atributo [Serializable]. Ex:

```
[Serializable]
public class Carro
{
     public int Codigo { get; set; }
     public string Marca { get; set; }
     public decimal Preco { get; set; }
     public bool AirBag { get; set; }
}
```

Criar um método para Clonar Objetos.

```
public static object ClonarObjeto(object objRecebido)
{
    using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
    {
        var bf = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();

        bf.Serialize(ms, objRecebido);
        ms.Position = 0;

        object obj = bf.Deserialize(ms);
        ms.Close();

        return obj;
    }
}
```

Enfim clonar os objetos:

```
List<Carro> listaCarros = new List<Carro>();
List<Carro> listaCarrosCopia = new List<Carro>();

listaCarros.Add(carroA);
listaCarros.Add(carroB);

foreach (Carro item in listaCarros)
    listaCarrosCopia.Add((Carro)ClonarObjeto(item));
```

Agora teremos duas listas independentes.

Comment: Muito obrigado, resultou e me ajudou muito!

Answer (score 4):

Faz com LINQ que é mais fácil:

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        var vaos = new List<Vao> {new Vao {Quantidade = 2, Medida = 2}, new Vao {Quantidade = 0, Medida = 0}, new Vao {Quantidade = 1, Medida = 1}};
        var ordenada = new List<Vao>(vaos);
        ordenada = vaos.OrderBy(p => p.Medida).Select(item => item.Clone()).ToList();
        ordenada[1].Medida = 5;
        foreach (var item in ordenada) WriteLine($"{item.Quantidade} x {item.Medida}");
        foreach (var item in vaos) WriteLine($"{item.Quantidade} x {item.Medida}");
    }
}

public class Vao {
    public int Quantidade { get; set; }
    public double Medida { get; set; }
    public Vao Clone() => (Vao)this.MemberwiseClone();
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/WLJwXc). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CsConsCore). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/CopyObject.cs).

Tem várias coisas bem inadequadas nesse código, mas o que foi perguntado está aí.

Comment: Obrigado @bigown pelo seu comentário mas não resolveu o meu problema, continua a ter dependência. Quando a List ordenada faz as alterações, os index's mudam também na primeira. Já agora o que acha que está inadequado no meu código ?

Comment: @DiogoSousa Fiz uma mudança para clonar o objeto. Recomendo você fazer um [mcve] para mostrar o problema acontecendo. Tem vários problemas, no código, tudo coisa pequena, se fosse grande não funcionaria, mas que vai deixando o código ruim. Esse não é o foco aqui.

Comment: ♦ já coloquei algumas imagens para tentar mostrar o que me está a acontecer. Vou tentar fazer o que me disse do clonar o objecto. Obrigado